# MS Access 2010 Ribbon rest

Tags: ms-access-2010

In design mode I have to keep resetting the ribbon to remove whatever customization are happening to the ribbon. How stop the ribbon from changing?

Example, I can build a query and/or form and I have to go reset the ribbon before I get the option to run the query or see the form in form mode.

I have compacted and repaired and I have created a new database and imported all objects into the new database.

What has happen? How can I fix this.

Comment: Maybe you have an Add-In installed that changes the ribbon? A screenshot may be helpful.

Comment: @Andre There are no Add-Ins at all. No AutoExc macros, or any vba establishing or messing with ribbons.

Comment: Have you've already checked `File | Options | Current Database | Ribbon Name` ? Also if it's happening on specific forms, you can check to see if the Ribbon property has been set under Form Properties in Design View - look on the Other tab

Comment: @dbmitch yes I have checked per your question. I have discovered if I hold the shift key when opening the database everything works normally. There are no forms set to open when opening the database. No special ribbons. I have compacted and repaired. I have even made a new database an imported all the objects and the problem returned.

Comment: If you hold the Shift key down and it works, then you have some startup code running. Check your options under CurrentDatabase and look at the startup form. Under the form load or open event there must be some code - or a macro that runs - visible via Properties|Events. You say there's no form set to open when you open the database - what is the first form that shows when you DON'T hold the shift key down - it must get opened by Autoexec or Current Database - Startup Form

Comment: @dbmitch No form opens when you first open the database, with or without the Shift key. I never use macros but I checked. No macros. The only on_form_load event code I have is checking and setting db=currentdb in for global use. I have no custom ribbons, what so ever, for any forms or reports or anything. This is just plain weird.